# My variable changes the value of the variable it is set to be

Tags: javascript

I want to set the value of semiusedcards to be the same as usedcards. but when i run the function: usedcards get updated without me setting a different value.

Code:

```
const cards = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
const colors = ['hearts', 'clubs', 'diamonds', 'spade'];
let usedcards = [];

function randomcard(){
  let semiusedcards = usedcards;
  if(semiusedcards.length != 52){
    let duplicate = false;
    let random1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
    let random2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 12);
    if(semiusedcards.length == 0){
      semiusedcards.push({'color': colors[random1], 'card': cards[random2]})
    }
    else{
      for(j = 0; j < semiusedcards.length; j++){
        if(semiusedcards[j].color == colors[random1] && semiusedcards[j].card == cards[random2]){
          duplicate = true
          //console.log('duplicate');
        }
      }
      if(duplicate == false){
        semiusedcards.push({'color': colors[random1], 'card': cards[random2]})
        //console.log('added');
      }
      else{
        randomcard()
      }
    }
  }
  let number = semiusedcards.length - 1;
  return semiusedcards[number];
}
```

Comment: You have to clone your list. Arrays are stored by reference, not by value in is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone your array list:

```
 let semiusedcards = [...usedcards];
```

This way you create a new list with the same entries.

Otherwise you just put a reference to the same list in semiusedcards variable